# Pytorch value error during train model (ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2))

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am making an image matching model as a task.
But there was an error in my assignment, and I searched for three hours, but I couldn't correct the error.
We desperately need your help.

This is my error message.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 5
      2 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
      4 # Train and evaluate
----> 5 model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer_ft, num_epochs=num_epochs)

Cell In[6], line 34, in train_model(model, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs)
     32 # track history if only in train
     33 with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
---> 34     outputs, aux_output = model(inputs)
     35     loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     36     _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Below is a part of my code that occurred.

```
# Setup the loss fxn
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Train and evaluate
model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders, criterion, optimizer_ft, num_epochs=num_epochs)
```

train_model()

```
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        # Each epoch has a training and validation phase
        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()  # Set model to training mode
            else:
                model.eval()   # Set model to evaluate mode

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            # Iterate over data.
            for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)

                # zero the parameter gradients
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                # track history if only in train
                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs, aux_output = model(inputs)
                    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                    # backward + optimize only if in training phase
                    # parameter update
                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: The problem is in the `forward` method of the model

Answer (score 0):

```py
---> 34     outputs, aux_output = model(inputs)
```

- This line of code tells python to unpack the return of the model's `forward` function into `outputs` and `aux_output`.
- The error means that the model's `forward` method's return can't be unpacked into 2 variables.
- To demonstrate, look at the following example

  ```py
  def foo():
      ...
      return out1, out2

  x, y = foo() # x, y are assigned out1 and out2 respectively
  ```
- This will throw the error

  ```py
  def bar():
      ...
      return out1
  x, y = bar() # This will throw the same error, unless out1 is itself a tuple of 2 elements
  ```
- Note that this will throw an error as well

  ```py
  def dummy_func():
      ...
      return out1, out2, out3
  x, y = dummy_func()
  ```
- So, the important thing to note is

  - Make sure that the function return can be unpacked into the correct number of variables you are assigning.
  - The function's return can be unpacked if it's a tuple, a list or even a tensor.
  - If the tuple size, list size, or the tensor's first dimension size is not equal to the number of parameters in the left hand side of the assignment, it will throw this error

#### Another part of the puzzle, what's `aux_outputs` doing?

Generally, models return the output as a tensor. So, if you didn't overwrite the `forward` method, I think you shouldn't unpack the output of the model into 2 variables.